STM32 - LTDC + DMA2D flickering and banding
I'm currently using an STM32H753 with 16bit SDRAM (IS42S16800F) to store an RGB565 buffer, with LTDC driving an 800x480 LCD. I'm using double-buffering, flipping the buffers in the LTDC vsync interrupt (enabling the RRIE interrupt and setting the VBR bit in SRCR). The graphics are being drawn to the backbuffer via DMA2D while LTDC reads from the frontbuffer.
If I render an image just once to both buffers, they both flip and display fine without any issues. I can see the framebuffer address in the debugger changing between subsequent VSYNC interrupts. However, if I try to update the screen repeatedly, I suddenly end up with strange flickering on the LCD. The image still renders correctly for the most part, but there are darker flickering bands across the screen that move slightly with each update.
In the image below, the purple-looking area is actually light grey and is where the banding occurs. At this point, the screen should be fully white, with a small orb rendered on top which is programmed to bounce around the screen. The orb displays correctly, aside from its colour appearing darker when it crosses the banded scanlines.

I've done a fair bit of reading on the potential causes, and my first thought was that perhaps I'm oversaturating the AXI bus/FMC used by both LTDC + DMA2D. However, I've enabled the LTDC's buffer underrun interrupt, and it never seems to occur, indicating it has no trouble reading the pixel data in time (to check I'd done this correctly, I temporarily clocked the FMC low enough to cause an underrun, and the interrupt occured right away)
I've also read ST's AN4861 document, and tried the following from it:

Confirmed my pixel clock is within useable range, considering my RAM width and colour depth (29MHz vs a 58MHz maximum)
Configured SDRAM memory regions with the MPU according to section 5.6.2
Ensured my total line width in bytes is a multiple of 64 (800 * 2)
Made sure to position both buffers in separate SDRAM banks with the same offset in each (first is at 0xC0000000, second is at 0xC0400000, which should be 4MB apart. My RAM has 4x 2Mx16 banks = 1 bank should be 4MB)

Other things I've tried:

Checking panel timing specs (I don't think this is the problem seeing as still images display fine with no rolling or other issues)
Setting highest read priority to LTDC on the AXI bus in the GPV QOS registers
Testing drawing with just a tiny image to reduce the total read/write load

Right now, I'm totally stumped as to what the cause could be. I'm pretty sure I can't be maxing the bandwidth with my hardware configuration and simple tests, but I really don't know. If anyone can help, I'd be very appreciative.

Are you sure yo're running the display interface at the right speed? (frame rate not just pixel clock)... LCDs start to behave strangely if you vary the timings outside what they want. This is my first guess for any shimmering, banding, flickering, etc... Don't forget to account for blanking periods in your calculations - look into the panel specs, not the uC's specs.

"still images display fine" likely isn't the validation you might think it is! Please feel free to identify the panel, and share its timings, and your calculations.
